# Let comments retain their pings when they are moved to chat

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, ping, comment-to-chat-migration

It often happens to me that someone has replied to (user @rus9384) me in comments, comments have been moved to chat, and I don't see the response (if the post is not mine, I don't see any notification that comments have been moved to chat, nor do I see the response if it has been made prior to the movement).

The solution would be to make moved comments (chat messages after the move) to retain their pings (if I didn't see them in my "Recent inbox messages" yet), so that I could see that someone replied to me even if replies have been moved to chat.